# How can I join paths with overlapping anchor points In Adobe Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Imagine you have really a lot of open paths. Some of those have overlapping anchor points while others don't have. Is it possible to simply select all the paths and run a command to join only those which have overlapping anchor points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a free script doing that "Merge Overlapped Anchors" and you can find it at [shspage.com](http://shspage.com/aijs/en#merge)

merges nearly overlapped anchor points.
also reports how many anchor points had been reduced.

just select the path(es) and run the script.

Comment: This is an excellent tool for merging stupid MATLAB segmented pdf exports!